# How to make a grid with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, grid, uicollectionview

i want to make a uicollectionview like this one:

[image: reference]

i have no idea, how to make the grid...i can put the image, but no the squares.

i've tried to use another UIImage view but, i need space between cells, so it's pretty useless.

ideas ? (and make it works on iPad too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to do two  things:

1. To show grid - Set border of collection view cell layer
2. To avoid spacing between cells - Create flowlayout object for your collection view:

   ```
   UICollectionViewFlowLayout * flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
   flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
   flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;


   UICollectionView * collectionview = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:frame collectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
collectionViewCell.layer.borderwidth...
```

Check this question out for the general idea - [Adding rounded corner and drop shadow to UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505379/adding-rounded-corner-and-drop-shadow-to-uicollectionviewcell)